# Polyglossia: babelshorthands stopped working in \title

Tags: babel, polyglossia, active-characters

I'm using polyglossia rather than babel for multilingual documents, with babel's shorthands activated for the German language so I can easily add explicit hyphens to words without breaking hyphenation, etc.

Last night I updated my MikTeX installation (previous update was in August), and explicit hyphens using `"=` now stopped working in `\title`s. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}
\title{Super"=duper Dokument}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Super"=duper Dokument.
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: MWE]

As you can see, the explicit hyphen `"=` works as expected in text, but not in the document title. It used to work until now, so I'm wondering if this is an intentional change or a bug that should be reported, and also whether there are any workarounds in the meantime.

FWIW passing `babelshorthands=true` as a package option rather than an optional argument to `\setmainlanguage` makes no difference, and there's nothing relevant in the log file, no error messages, warnings etc.

Thanks for the help and happy holidays!

Comment: Move the `\title{Super"=duper Dokument}` to after `\begin{document}`. The shorthands are usually not active in the preamble to avoid interference with package code. (https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/368 could be related, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: That did it, excellent! Funny that --- I was taught that having ``\title`` etc. in the preamble rather than the document body was ,,cleaner``, as it were. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I see where that argument is coming from, but I think usually the advice is exactly the opposite: Use `\title` after `\begin{document}` to make sure that shorthands and other language settings are already active. I tested the MWE with `babel` and the result is the same. The shorthand only works after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I would leave the title in the preamble (I find this cleaner too) and use `\shorthandon{"}` before it.

Comment: With `babel` there is an alternative approach - write `\babelshorthand{"=}` instead of just `"=`, which works even if shorthands have not been activated (this macro is meant for cases like this).